# Critical Points of $\sin(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: calculus

So I was asked to find critical points and also determine why I can't use the second derivative to find it. Well, the discriminant is always $0$ $(f_{xx}  f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2)$
on those points and that's why you can't say what kind of critical points are they.
Yet they still ask me to find the types, I'm having a hard time since we didn't learn any other way to determine critical points. Am I missing something here?

Could use some help or hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Critical points are exactly those satisfying $$\cos (x^2+y^2) = 0$$
and the point $(0,0)$, which should be treated separately.

Note that $\cos(x^2+y^2)=0$ implies $\sin(x^2+y^2)= \pm 1$. Since $\sin (\mbox{anything})$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, you can see that these points are maximums or minimums, according to (respectively) $\sin(x^2+y^2)=1$ or $\sin(x^2+y^2)=-1$.

As for the point $(0,0)$, you can proceed normally with the discriminant (wich is $\neq 0$) to show that it is a minimum point.